# SearchBar plugin not showing with TabBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, searchbar

For my Flutter project I added `loader_search_bar` plugin and also added `Tabbar`.This my code

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar:SearchBar(
            defaultBar: AppBar(
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: null,
              ),
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
                ],
              ),
              title: Text('Default app bar title'),
            ),
            //   onQueryChanged: (query) => _handleQueryChanged(context, query),
            onQuerySubmitted: (query){print(query);},
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is the result[image: Screen].
As you can see in the Screenshot Searchbar not showing. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap with PreferredSize works fine. You can see full code below

code snippet

```
DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
          child: SearchBar(
            defaultBar: AppBar(
```

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loader_search_bar/loader_search_bar.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
          child: SearchBar(
            defaultBar: AppBar(
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: null,
              ),
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
                ],
              ),
              title: Text('Default app bar title'),
            ),
            //   onQueryChanged: (query) => _handleQueryChanged(context, query),
            onQuerySubmitted: (query) {
              print(query);
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```